# JSON, полученный с сервера

Tags: java, android, json

Учусь работать с Android, использую этот пример: http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/
Все замечательно, выводит в лог, вероятно глупый вопрос, но как получить этот массив для использования в других функциях?

Comment: Передать в качестве параметра/сохранить в поле класса/сохранить где либо ещё(в каком то глобальном хранилище например)

Comment: Опишите проблему с которой столкнулись с примером кода, желательно. А то сейчас ваш вопрос слишком общий и не имеет однозначного ответа.

Comment: @eugeneek код целиком взят из примера. вопрос в том, как использовать полученный jsonarray в oncreate для примера

Comment: В `onCreate` никак, так как получаете вы его асинхронно. Создайте другой метод, передавайте полученный jsonarray в него в качестве параметра и используйте уже в нём.